# after background subtraction how to track certain object in masked area?

Tags: opencv, surf, background-subtraction

I have implemented background subtraction code and it works fine but after that how could I make use of the generated mask (to decrease the processing needed )to follow single object that I have its image before. I tried FAST with Flann matcher but it keep giving wrong matches!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/91mPc.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBfyL.png

Comment: could you provide some sample images, please?

Comment: i hope the images i have added help, thanks for following